# Javascript Script to Confirm a Users Information

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I'm currently creating a website, and I am trying to create a javascript script that will accept a users input into an InputField and then confirm their input (which will be an ID) from  my SQL database. Does anybody know what the script would be to confirm that ID from the database? Or something similar?

Comment: You can't do this just in Javascript. You need a script on the server that queries the SQL database. Then you can use AJAX to call that script and confirm the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can't communicate with a database server directly.
The most common way to get information from a database in javascript is by using a techinque called AJAX.

The basic outline of AJAX is as follows:

Somewhere in the javascript a request is made to the webserver the site is hosted at. The webserver will handle this request with its webserver magic (for example a PHP script), and respond with whatever this script created.
Then, the javascript can use the information recieved from the webserver to do the things it wanted to do.

In your case you would probably want something like this:

- The javascript sends the id to the webserver.
- The webserver recieves the id from the javascript request and asks the database if it exists or if it correct or whatever.
- Then the database responds with some data, which the webserver can then process.
- The processed information will be used to respond to the request javascript made.
- Javascript recieves the data from the webserver and does with it what it needs to.

This is a very rough outline, though. AJAX is a beautiful tool to have at our disposal, but it can be a pain to implement (especially considering safety).

Try to find some tutorials on basic AJAX implementations and techniques and I'm sure you'll be alright!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using a programming language that isn't client-side also, you could pull down all the ID's from the database and then convert them into a javascript array/variable, which you could then loop over to compare to the input-field.

If you are not using another programming language, Javascript cannot directly connect to MySQL - It needs to be mixed with a server-side language like Php, java, c# etc.